# How do I prove that $\{f\in L^p(\Bbb{R}): \{f\neq 0\} ~\text{is bounded in } \Bbb{R}\}$ is dense in $L^p(\Bbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, dense-subspaces

> Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and take the set $\Bbb{R}$ equipped with the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra. Define $L_c^p(\Bbb{R})=\{f\in L^p(\Bbb{R}): \{f\neq 0\} ~\text{is bounded in } \Bbb{R}\}$. I need to show that $L_c^p(\Bbb{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\Bbb{R})$

My idea was to show that $L_c^p(\Bbb{R})$ is closed and it's closure is $L^p(\Bbb{R})$ then we would be done. But I have some problems in proving that it's closed. If I take a convergent subsequence $f_n$ in $L_c^p(\Bbb{R})$, say $f_n\rightarrow f\in L^p(\Bbb{R})$ then how can I show that $\{f\neq 0\}$ is bounded?

Could maybe someone help me how to solve this exercise?

Comment: Not that if $L_c^P(\mathbb{R})$ were closed *and* its closure were $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, we would have $L_c^p(\mathbb{R}) = L^p (\mathbb{R})$, which is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given $n$ let $f_n:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, $x\mapsto\unicode{120793}\{-n\le x\le n\}f(x)$. Notice that $|f_n|^p$ is non-negative and converges to $|f|^p$ from below, so by the monotone convergence theorem we have $\|f_n\|_p^p\rightarrow\|f\|_p^p$. Notice that $|f(x)-f_n(x)|^p=\unicode{120793}\{x\not\in[-n,n]\}|f|^p$ and hence $\|f-f_n\|_p^p=\|f\|_p^p-\|f_n\|_p^p\rightarrow 0$. This completes the proof, since every point is a limit point of functions with bounded support.

Comment: The above already shows that $L^p(\mathbb R)$ is the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)#Closure_of_a_set), since this is a metric space. To be specific, this shows that $L^p(\mathbb R)$ is in the closure of $L_c^p(\mathbb R)$. For the other direction, say, $L_c^p(\mathbb R)$ is a subset of the closed set $L^p(\mathbb R)$ (in the topology of $L^p(\mathbb R)$), so the closure is, too, since it's the intersection of all closed sets containing $L_c^p(\mathbb R)$.